# Cakephp saving values into data base

Tags: model, cakephp-2.1

I'm having a Movies table and a Rating table. Ratings table belongsTo Movies and Movies hasOne Rating. I want to increment the "vote_count" field. The code is as below.

```
public function set_ratings($movieId, $value){
    $this->Movie->id = $movieId;
    $rateMovie = $this->Movie->read();
    $oldNoOfVotes = $rateMovie['Rating']['number_of_votes'];
    debug($oldNoOfVotes);
    $newNoOfVotes = ++$oldNoOfVotes;
    $newVoteCount = $rateMovie['Rating']['vote_count'] + $value;
    $newAverageRating = $newVoteCount / $newNoOfVotes;
    debug($oldNoOfVotes);
    debug($newNoOfVotes);
    $this->request->data['Rating']['id'] = $rateMovie['Rating']['id'];
    $this->request->data['Rating']['number_of_votes'] = $newNoOfVotes;
    $this->request->data['Rating']['vote_count'] = $newVoteCount;
    $this->request->data['Rating']['average_rating'] = $newAverageRating;
    //$this->request->data['Rating']['id'] =  $rateMovie['Rating']['id'];
    debug($newNoOfVotes);
    $this->Movie->Rating->save($this->request->data);
    debug($newNoOfVotes);
}
```

The problem what I'm facing is that if the "vote_count" is say 15 and when I increment it and debug the value is 16, but in the DB it is getting saved as 18. What is the reason?

Comment: did you debug($newVoteCount) ... ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you don't call the function twice or more? Or maybe the database engine increments it (something like ON UPDATE increment SQL statement)?